# Who all constitute algebraic numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, self-learning, transcendental-numbers

Algebraic numbers are numbers which are roots of polynomial with rational coefficients. What all constitutes these numbers. Transcendental numbers are those which can not be roots of above. And wiki says ex as $\pi$ and e

Can you pls elaborate on this what all are included under algebraic number?

1. square root of prime? (My thinking $x^2 - p = 0$ , p is prime) so all square root of prime are algebraic
2. all complex numbers - wiki says yes (My thinking - $x^2+1 = 0$ )

**3. All irrationals? -- i could think of some irrationals like $x^2-2 = 0$. How to conclude all irrationals as algebraic?**All irrationals are algebraic? iirational means non-recurring non-terminating decimal number.

4. All rationals? - I think yes $ xa+b = 0$ and $a$ and $ b$ are co-prime right?
5. All primes? --> (my thinking - x-p = 0, p is prime)
6. Any other?

Some may think that it is stupid Qn, may be yes. But before downvoting or recommending to delete it, atleast enlighten me! I am a beginner and learning on my own. So i have posted here to clarify my ignorance. pardon me for being so stupid.

---

can u please elaborate on what kind of irrationals make them not algebraic? (i know only pi and e) . I got this question when i was thinking on $\sqrt p, p$ a prime number set is subset of irrationals(which are uncountable) yet countable. But on other side algebraic numbers are countable.

That made me to think **what subset of irrationals are not countable**. So went to wiki for seeing algebraic numbers and rest all here.

Comment: What have you tried? You have written that algebraic numbers are numbers which are roots of polynomials with rational coefficients. Have you tried to think of a polynomial which has $\sqrt{p}$, where $p$ is a prime, as a root? Hint: a relatively simple polynomial works. In fact it suffices for $p$ to be a positive integer, not just prime.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as self-learning, one tip is to look at small degree polynomials and see what kinds of roots they can have. For example, $ax + b = 0$ has roots of the form $-\frac{b}{a}$, so if $a,b$ are rational then so is the root. What about polynomials with degree $2$? Degree $3$ and beyond is too much to do by hand but you can try some special cases and see what patterns you recognize.

Comment: For 1, 4 and 5 the answer is yes and you should be able to prove this directly from the definition (as @aras is hinting). For 2 and 3 you think "yes", but you have already mentioned counterexamples before that: $\pi$ and $e$...

Comment: sir i have edited my thinking. Pls have a look and clarify.

Comment: For the record I find the downvotes a bit harsh, definitely after the edit. In my opinion OP shows effort (again, definitely after the edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, algebraic numbers are numbers which are roots a a polynomial in $\mathbf Z[X]$. Among these, algebraic integers are numbers which are root of a *monic* polynomial in $\mathbf Z[X]$.

Therefore the answer to 1, 4 and 5 is yes (albeit, in the case of rationals, it has nothing to do with $a$ and $b$ being coprime).

The answer to 2 is No: some complex numbers are algebraic, others are not. Anyway, remember  a real number is also a complex number. For instance $\pi i$ is transcendental.

The answer to 3 is also No. Actually the irrationals are by definition the numbers which are *not* rational. So either they're algebraic or they're transcendental.

Comment: Thank you sir .... also sir can u please elaborate on what kind of irrationals make them not algebraic? (i know only pi and e) . I got this question when i was thinking on $\sqrt p, p$ a prime number set is subset of irrationals yet countable. But on other side algebraic numbers are countable. That made me to think what subset of irrationals are not countable. So went to wiki for seeing algebraic numbers and rest all here.

Comment: Transcendental numbers have the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: sir any book to read on this further for proof and how these transcedental numbers look like (i only saw pi and e as transcedental numbers nd know nothing about them)? can you pls give me a subset of irrationals which are uncountable(apart from transcedental numbers)? Also  i checked rudin and bartle real analysis book but could not find much on these concepts

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#The_existence_of_Liouville_numbers_(Liouville's_constant) for a construction that gives an explicit uncountable collection of transcendental numbers. @NascimentodeCos